# How to find files with text started with

Tags: regex, linux, grep, find, pcregrep

I tried to use

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep -slE '^asdasd' {} \;
```

and

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.php' -exec pcregrep -l '^asdasd' {} \;
```

But this commands found files, where 'asdasd' in beginning of lines, not of all text, for example:

File content:

```
qweqwe

asdasd

czczc
```

I want to find files only with this file content:

```
asdasd

qwdq

qwdad
```

(asdasd in beginning of all text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` you can check if the first line matches whatever saying:

```
awk 'NR==1 && /pattern/' file
```

If you want to print its file name, then say:

```
awk 'NR==1 && /pattern/ {print FILENAME}'
```

To combine it with `find` and check if the first line starts with "asdasd", use:

```
find -type f -exec awk 'NR==1 && /^asdasd/ {print FILENAME}' {} \;
```

Comment: Ok! I will do it. 
Something else:
Do you know why it impossible do with pcregrep? It seems pcregrep and grep work in multiline mode only. Or they ignore '^'

Comment: @user2371331 no, I don't know - I don't have experience with `pcregrep`, since `grep` alone and `awk` serve me very well.

Answer (score 0):

`^(asdasd|qwdq|qwdad)` to regexp only part you want to find
OR 
`^(asdasd|qwdq|qwdad).*` to regexp full line